# Google Sheets: Return Multi Dimensional Array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Let's assume I have four existing arrays:

```
var one =   ["apple","banana","berry"];
var two =   ["fobar", "barfoo", "farboo"];
var three = [13, 421];
var four =  ["seven", "eight", "eleven"];
```

How would I merge them into one array and return it in the most simple way?
    What I got is

> var result = [one, two, three, four];

resulting in

```
|-----------------------------|
|  apple  |  banana  | berry  |  
|  foobar |  barfoo  | farboo |  
|  13     |  421     |        |
|  seven  |  eight   | eleven |
|-----------------------------|
```

However, what I actually need is this:

```
|------------------------------------|
|  apple  |  foobar  | 13  |  seven  |
|  banana |  barfoo  | 421 |  eight  |
|  berry  |  farboo  |     |  eleven |
|------------------------------------|
```

Comment: Warning to those answering: Google Apps Script is roughly ES3 (yes, 3) plus some standard library features from ES5. (I hear there's an update in the works, though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var output = one.map(function(e,i){
  return [e].concat([two, three, four].map(function(f){
    return f[i] === undefined ? '': f[i];
  }))
})
console.info(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays, it has arrays of arrays.

If you don't already have the `one`, `two`, `three`, `four` arrays, you can do it with a single nested literal:

```
var result = [
    ["apple", "fobar", 13, "seven"],
    ["banana", "barfoo", 421, "eight"],
    ["berry", undefined, "eleven"]
];
```

Live Example:

```js
var result = [
    ["apple", "fobar", 13, "seven"],
    ["banana", "barfoo", 421, "eight"],
    ["berry", "farboo", undefined, "eleven"]
];
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

If you do already have them, since they're arrays of column values and apparently you want the subarrays to be row values, you need to loop:

```
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    result[i] = [
        one[i], two[i], three[i], four[i]
    ];
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var one =   ["apple","banana","berry"];
var two =   ["fobar", "barfoo", "farboo"];
var three = [13, 421];
var four =  ["seven", "eight", "eleven"];
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    result[i] = [
        one[i], two[i], three[i], four[i]
    ];
}
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```